# font-scaling with root element and rem in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-scaling

I am using the `<html>` tag to define the global font-size and using `rem` to scale the font. Since I am building a web-component that would be included in many other applications. Hence defining the font size on the `<html>` tag will break consumers font-size. So how to solve this issue.

Is there any possibilities REM to calculate the font size not from HTML tag as root element but the root of my `web-component`?

I want to define the base-font size not on the `<html>` tag, but on a web-component... any other workaround would be also fine.

```js
function getDeviceName(width) {
  let deviceType = 'Mobile';
  if(window.screen.width < 768) {
    deviceType = 'Mobile';
  } else if(width >= 768 && width < 1201) {
    deviceType = 'Tablet';
  } else if(width >= 1201) {
    deviceType = 'Desktop';
  } 
  return deviceType;
}

function detectDeviceWidth(row, width) {
  const { fontSize, lineHeight } = window.getComputedStyle(row);
  row.innerText = `${getDeviceName(width)} - ${fontSize}/${lineHeight}`;
}

function triggerMediaQueries() {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  Array.from(rows).forEach(detectDeviceWidth);
}

window.addEventListener('load', triggerMediaQueries);

var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const cr = entry.contentRect;
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
    Array.from(rows).forEach(row => detectDeviceWidth(row, cr.width));
  }
});

// Observe one or multiple elements
ro.observe(document.body);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 24px;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 112.5%;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75.0625rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 137.5%;
    line-height: 33px;
  }
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .container {
    padding: 100px;
  }
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  color: #666666;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

.font100 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

.font200 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.font300 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.font400 {
  font-size: 1.1875rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}

.font500 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.font600 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
}

.font700 {
  font-size: 2.3125rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .row {
    border: 3px solid green;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75.0625rem) {
  .row {
    border: 3px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Font value 100</h3>
  <div class="font100 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 200</h3>
  <div class="font200 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 300</h3>
  <div class="font300 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 400</h3>
  <div class="font400 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 500</h3>
  <div class="font500 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 600</h3>
  <div class="font600 row"></div>
  <h3>Font value 700</h3>
  <div class="font700 row"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my rule for font-scaling

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 24px;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 112.5%;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75.0625rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 137.5%;
    line-height: 33px;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/rajkeshwar-the-bold/pen/PMwRGe

Comment: use `em` instead? `em` is the font size of the parent element. So if none of the ancestors have their font size set, then it will be relative to the web-component container (if that has it set).  [Have a read of this article](https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/)

Comment: Most of the element has its own `font-size`. Since `em` always calculates the `font-size` from it's parent element which has the `font-size` set. Hence it would be significant code change for most of the element. I was wondering is there any way to let `rem` to take `web-component` root as the root element instead of `html` tag.

Comment: In that case no - rem is taken from the base font size - that's the way it is defined and that's the way it works

Comment: You are thinking far too much in into this. `rem` means relative to the document font size. Document font size is the size of `1em` as applicable to the root element -- `html`. In fact, `font-size: 1em` and `font-size: 1rem` when specified for the root element, are *equivalent*. If you don't want to override document font -- because your component will be reused for other documents than your own -- then do not specify it on the root element. If you need to adjust relative sizes use `em` units on descendant elements of your component. If you absolutely want a baseline size, use CSS variables.

Comment: @RajkeshwarPrasad as far as I understand you want CSS rules inside your web component to use the root elements (that of the component) font size as "rem value". Can't you achieve this by simply setting a fixed pixel size on the web component root element and inherit from that using em? (just to be clear though, I'm currently not seeing any use of web components in your code)

Answer (score 0):

simply use `em`. `em` is relative to the parent element whereas `rem` is relative to the root element. in case you apply `em` to the root element, it would be equivalent to `rem`.